# Randomly placed circles sometimes go out of the canvas when the code says otherwise

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, random, p5.js

I have a bunch of circles that are randomly placed from `0 + circle radius` to `height/width - circle radius` but for some reason, once in a while, one of them goes outside of the canvas even though the code says otherwise (that one is dark gray for development purposes.)

```js
const circlesToMake = 50;
let circleLayer, circles, r, g, b;
let lives = 3;
let round = -1;
let dead = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  noStroke();
  textFont('JetBrains Mono');
  setupCircles();
  fill(0);
  noLoop();
  circleLayer = createGraphics(width, height);
}

function draw() {
  image(circleLayer, 0, 0);
  fill(0);
  drawCircles(circleLayer);
  dispInfo();
}

function setupCircles() {
  circles = []
  r = random(20, 235)
  g = random(20, 235)
  b = random(20, 235)
  round++;

  while (circles.length < circlesToMake) {
    const circle = {
      x: random(width),
      y: random(height),
      r: 20,
    };

    let overlapping = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
      const other = circles[j];
      const d = dist(circle.x, circle.y, other.x, other.y);

      if (d < circle.r + other.r) {
        overlapping = true;
      } if (circle.x < 0 + circle.r || circle.x > width - circle.r) {
        overlapping = true;
      } if (circle.y < 0 + circle.r || circle.y > height - circle.r) {
        overlapping = true;
      }
    }

    if (!overlapping) {
      circles.push(circle);
    }
  }
}

function drawCircles(circleLayer) {
  clear();
  stroke(0);
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, width-1, height-1);
  noStroke();
  circles.forEach(c => {
    fill(r, g, b, 200); ellipse(c.x, c.y, c.r * 2, c.r * 2);
  });
  
  // fill(r, g, b, 220); // normal
  fill(32, 32, 32, 255); // dev mode
  
  const target = circles[0];
  ellipse(target.x, target.y, target.r * 2, target.r * 2);
}

function dispInfo() {
  fill(0, 0, 0, 100);
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
  text(`Lives: ${lives}`, 10, 10);
  text(`Round: ${round + 1}`, 10, 25);
}

function youDied() {
  clear();
  dead = true;
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(20);
  fill (0, 0, 0);
  text(`You survived ${round} rounds.`, width/2, height/2);
  fill(r, g, b, 255);
  ellipse(circles[0].x, circles[0].y, circles[0].r * 2, circles[0].r * 2);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (!dead) {
    if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, circles[0].x, circles[0].y) < circles[0].r) {
      setupCircles();
      drawCircles();
      redraw();
    } else {
      const wrongClick = circles.some(c => dist(mouseX, mouseY, c.x, c.y) < c.r);
      if (wrongClick) {
        lives--;
        redraw();
      } if (lives <= 0) {
        youDied();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I tried to add an `if` statement so that when the random `x` or `y` values are greater than `0 + radius` or less than `height - radius`/`width - radius` it rerolls the values but it just doesn't work for the `target` circle (`circles[0]`) sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x: random(width)` puts the center of the circle between 0 and the width. But that doesn't account for the radius of the circle.

Take the radius into consideration so the center of the circle is between `radius` and `width - radius`:

```js
const radius = 20;
const circle = {
  x: random(radius, width - radius),
  y: random(radius, height - radius),
  r: radius,
};
```

Comment: I tried this and tested it 50 times and it worked, so thanks!! I also changed the radius constant to `radius` to remove any confusion between `r` for the red amount and `r` for radius.